# php echo not working after elseif

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, simplexml

I am trying to extract data from an XML file using simplexml.  I am running a series of while and foreach loops to dig down to what I need.

However, I have found that after the elseif is finished I can no long display additional data to the screen (echo and print_r don't work).  I have attached a code snippet for the elseif loop through the end of the end of the script.  Please excuse the lousy code, I am a relatively new programmer.

```
elseif ($select_vars[1]==-1) {
    $sub1=0;
    $sub2=0;
    $temp_count = 1;
    $modnum=intval($select_vars[0]);
    $sub1m =  $xmls->module->{
        intval($select_vars[0])}

    ->count();
    while ($sub1 < $sub1m) {
        foreach($xmls->module->{
            $modnum}

        ->sublist1->{
            $sub1}

        as $hit2){
            $sub2m =  $xmls->module->{
                $modnum}

            ->sublist1->{
                $sub1}

            ->count();
            while ($sub2 < $sub2m) {
                foreach($xmls->module->{
                    $modnum}

                ->sublist1->{
                    $sub1}

                ->sublist2->{
                    $sub2}

                as $hit3){
                    $template_string .= $temp_count . " - " . (string)$hit3 . "<br/>";
                    $temp_count = $temp_count+1;
                    $template_list[] = (string)$hit3;
                }

                $sub2 = $sub2+1;
            }

            $sub1 = $sub1+1;
            $sub2 = 0;
        }

    }

    echo "sub1 = " . $sub1 . "<br/>";
}

echo "here <br/><br/>".$template_string;
print_r ($template_list);
$template_list = array_unique($template_list);
sort($template_list);
print_r ($template_list);
```

I know the loops extract the right information because I can echo anywhere in the various loops except after the esleif closing bracket.

A live copy of the code is available at: http://www.aquilasolutions.us/software/templates/pages/filter-list.php

EDIT:

The output SHOULD be 3 selects and when the top box is filled when the others are empty a series of line (up to 400+) in the format ### - ####-####-####-#### should appear.

EDIT 2:
To View the error:
1. set select "Module " to be anything
2. Set select sublist 1 and sublist 2 to be empty
3. Make sure the array at the top has 3 keys (it represents a session cookie called filter-list and represents the selected items)

EDIT 3:
I have tracked down the error but not been able to resolve it.

There is a fatal error in my log (Fatal error:  Call to a member function count() on null) on the line:

$sub2m =  $xmls->module->{$modnum}->sublist1->{$sub1}->count();

I tried putting an isnull catch in but then there was a fatal error on the isnull....

Comment: Hem... It works on your demo ? Ah no ok... It is not the echo that is not "working". It is about your variables you are trying to dump...

Comment: You are seeing almost 400 lines in the format # - ####-####-####-#### and an array dump?

Comment: The code's working fine. The variables are simply empty.

Comment: I thought of that.  Notice the "echo "here <br/><br/>".$template_string;"  That will show "here" even if the variable is empty.  Plus if I move any of the echos or print_rs inside the elseif loop they work.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down the issue and as expected it was my own stupidity!

I typed the wrong variable for the while ($sub2 < $sub2m) loop.

It SHOULD have been while ($sub2 < $sub2num)